# DataPropertyName doesn't work with user-defined column name in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When I call a procedure in database which has the following query:

```
select id,name,idCategory,format(price,'#,#')as price from [MyTable]
```

There is a column named `price` when I run the query itself.

However, in my DataGridView I get a bonus **'Column 1'** column and my **'Price'** column is left empty although I have set 'Price''s DataProperty to be `price`.

Is my query causing the problem because the name is only abstract? How can I solve this?

Comment: Personally, rather than using `FORMAT` (which is an awfully slow function) I would simply return the value of `price` and then do the formatting in your datagridview. The display format of data is (almost) always better to be done in your presentation layer. With things like numbers and dates, this is especially true.

Comment: Did the DataGridView not have a property to autocreate columns ?

Comment: I think I deserve to be down-voted since I called the wrong SP for a nearly similar table. I only put testing data in my tables so I didn't recognize the differences. Sorry guys...

Comment: @TrungĐặng mistakes will be made for everybody while humans do the coding, dont worry.